# Why do I need to change `var value = val;` to `this.value = val;` so I don't get a "undefined" error?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and my background is Java.  Why do I need to change `var value = val;` to `this.value = val;` so I don't get a "undefined" error when I use `console.log(node.value);` to print out the values I pushed, but no need to change `var next = {};` to `this.next = {};`?

```
var LinkedList = function(e) {
  var first, last;

  var Node =function(val) {
    var value = val;
    var next = {};
  }
  this.push = function(val) {
    var node = new Node(val);
    if (first == null) {
      console.log(node.value);
      first = last = node;
    }
    else {
      console.log(node.value);
      last.next = node;
      last = node;
    }
  }
}

var list = new LinkedList();
list.push(1);
list.push(2);
list.push(3);
```

Comment: `var value` should probably be `this.value`

Comment: "Get undefined error" *where* exactly? Also, your `var Node = function ..` essentially does nothing as it is. It's pretty pointless unless you use `this.`.

Comment: I would imagine that you are having trouble because there is a conflict with `Node` which is a native function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the 'var' keyword in an objects methods (including its constructor) makes that variable private. Although you can access it in other 'priviledge' methods of that object, you cant access it outside those. Therefore, trying to gets you undefined.

Conversely, using this.name to assign a variable makes it public, which means trying to access it from outside the object works.

I found this article to be helpful on the subject. http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Answer (score 0):

1. You're not getting an *error*, your logging statement merely outputs `undefined` because `node` does not have a property called `value`.
2. This essentially does nothing:

   ```
     var Node = function(val) {
         var value = val;
         var next = {};
     }
   ```

   You're defining two locally scoped variables, but nothing is ever accessing those variables. The variables are not accessible outside this `function () { }` literal. The `first` and `last` variables of your `LinkedList` work the same way. Try `console.log(list.first)`, that's `undefined` as well.

   If you want to create the properties `value` and `next` on the new object instance (`this`), you need to do this with `this.value` and `this.next`.
3. The reason you're not seeing any problem with `next` is because you're never outputting it, and you're explicitly creating it anyway here:

   ```
   last.next = node;
   ```

   Until this line the `.next` property didn't exist.